# Cannot deploy profiles - no RecordType named idea.Record_type_for_community

Tags: apex, ideas

Cannot deploy profiles - no RecordType named idea.Record_type_for_community.

We have no record types defined in any org. Still we are getting this error while migrating.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: if you retrieve all of your metadata, isn't this Record Type being referenced somewhere?